How to get a table from google docs using a URL in python
I've got this google doc URL that I need to extract the contents from, specifically the contents in the table.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vSHesOf9hv2sPOntssYrEdubmMQm8lwjfwv6NPjjmIRYs_FOYXtqrYgjh85jBUebK9swPXh_a5TJ5Kl/pub
I need to do this in python but I'm lost on how to extract that data.
I've tried the requests module and I've looked into the Docs API but I'm not understanding how to use them correctly since they just throw me errors.

In your situation, do you know the document ID of the Google Document you want to retrieve? Also, the Google Document is publicly shared?

Post what you have tried and a [mre]. [so] can provide much higher quality help with a specific problem.

To get you started, I was able to get the page with response = requests.get('https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vSHesOf9hv2sPOntssYrEdubmMQm8lwjfwv6NPjjmIRYs_FOYXtqrYgjh85jBUebK9swPXh_a5TJ5Kl/pub'). I can see the table in the response  (response.content). You'll need to parse that with something, beautifulsoup is my first choice, but there are others.

I also suggest inspecting the page with your browser's tools to find what you want (Chrome -> More Tools -> Developer Tools -> Elements is an example). It provides a nice GUI for inspecting it. It's much easier to grok than the raw response.

As a simple approach, how about df = pd.read_html("https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vSHesOf9hv2sPOntssYrEdubmMQm8lwjfwv6NPjjmIRYs_FOYXtqrYgjh85jBUebK9swPXh_a5TJ5Kl/pub")?
